# How to handle unicode characters in a powershell script from an api

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that calls an API which returns back data that I then use further on in the script. Part of the data is a string which will contain characters from other languages like Russian, French, etc.
I have tried the api in postman, and the string is as expected, so it looks like an issue in the powershell script. When I use the string it no longer contains Russian chars, but other chars.

Sample chars: дующее предупр

what I see in powershell: ÐµÐ¶Ð´Ð°ÑÑÐµÐ

What do I need to do to get the correct chars to come through?

Comment: Please show an example of the API call - what program / cmdlet are you using? One possible cause: if the API returns UTF-8-encoded text but doesn't declare it as such in the response header, PowerShell will interpret it as ISO-8859-1-encoded

Comment: It is an internally developed api so I unfortunately can't share. I will contact the development team for the api and see if we can get the information in the header.
Looking at the response header I'm getting, and assuming you are referring to this key, Content-Encoding, its value is 'gzip'

Comment: Looks like my issue was more related to the version of powershell I was using. I didn't realize it was running with v4. Once I got it to run under v7, the issue went away.

Comment: Good to know - not sure why it solved this particular problem, but it's worth nothing that the cross-platform [PowerShell (Core}](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) edition (v6+) now consistently defaults to (BOM-less) UTF-8 for _file_ operations. The header field I was referring to is `charset` (`Content-Encoding` usually relates to additional encoding for _compression_ purposes).